# Are Firestore downloads counted in realtime database download quota?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to make an android app with chat and user profiles. I want to save user information as firestore documents and keep chats in realtime database. But I was wondering.

Say 10GB/month of quota for downloading from one Realtime database, would it be accounted for by Firestore as well?

If I for example download information about 20 users from a firestore, let's say thats 500kb of data. Would such quota be also counted into my realtime database usage (500kb/10GB), or accounted separately and I only need to plan the costs on document reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore and the Realtime Database are two different database services offered by Firebase.

Respective cost calculations are totally separated, as well as the way quotas are defined.